# I have class that class have only X and Name Need to pass 3 diffrent values how?

Tags: c#

Hi I have problem with my code i have class , that class contain a Y and Name I just pass 3 diffrent values

```
        List<Cat> ddf = new List<Cat>();
        int val = 0;

        val = 20;
        val = 30;
        val = 40;


        Cat dd = new Cat();
        dd.y = val;
        dd.name = "First";
        ddf.Add(dd);

        Cat dd2 = new Cat();
        dd2.y = val;
        dd2.name = "secound";
        ddf.Add(dd2);

        Cat dd3 = new Cat();
        dd3.y = val;
        dd3.name = "Thrid";
        ddf.Add(dd3);
```

When i debug the code List adding last value only val = 40; when i check the ddf all 3 names are showing same values how to fix it please help me

Comment: Can any one help me please...

Comment: please try to debug your code first, you could have identified this your own. if you are new in c# then it's fine. you can check ms docs for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I edited some code this problem is last value only coming

Comment: Yes because you are overwriting dd.y value with last val value. It's not an array, it's an variable it can only hold 1 value at a timr

Comment: Create 3 different different variables, and then use them.

Comment: I cannot create 3diffrent varibale it becuase need to show barchart barchrart have only YAsis only Y value

Comment: Yes, what I am saying create int y1=20; then dd.y=y1; like this I am saying .

Comment: @kandeepan sabanathan could you please explain the barchart part? I mean how do you want to use the list in barchat? We will try best to help you to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `dd` one-by-one:

```
             List<Cat> ddf = new List<Cat>();
             Cat dd = new Cat();
             dd.y=40;
             dd.name = "First";
             ddf.Add(dd);

             Cat dd2 = new Cat();
             dd2.y = 20;
             dd2.name = "secound";
             ddf.Add(dd2);

             Cat dd3 = new Cat();
             dd3.y = 30;
             dd3.name = "Thrid";
             ddf.Add(dd3);
```

Now, the list `ddf` will have three `Cat` instances.

Comment: You're welcome. If works, please make it as answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: val = 40; name is all 3 But value is coming only last Can you help me please

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: For exmaple first -40 and secound-40 third-40

Comment: I checked your codes, you assigned the values to `val` three times, and only the latest one stored, so you surely get all `40`. You should define different variables if you want store different values.